# Resource files doesn't get updated in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I was trying to update an accdb file in my resource using VS 2010. But the problem is even thought I updated it, when I opened the original file in the resource folder using MS Access, I found that the file hasn't been changed at all.

I'm pretty sure that I've already updated the file in VS but after I opened the aacdb with Access, I found that the data in Visual Studio also returned to the original file.

I want that the updates I did in Visual Studio also went to the original file. I'm using C#.

Comment: resources are read only at runtime....

Comment: So...what should i do to update the resource file? I mean every time i open the original file it keeps resetting itself to the original version

Comment: don't embed it as a resource....!

Comment: As much as i want to do that, i can't my college project demands me to use it as a resource

Comment: I can't help with arbitrary and somewhat silly college requirements.